# How to store secure information in a data file

Tags: java, file-io

In my server-client program I want to know if the client is official (so, not modified). For that I want to implement a version check and the version should be stored in a data file or something. The problem is, how to store this securely? I don't want it to be readable with any sort of text reader, and if someone would modify the client, it must still not be usable for the modified program.

I already tried several things, like using a `Data In/Out Stream`, or an `Object In/Out Stream`, but they all remain slightly visible in a program like Notepad++, and still they can be used by any non-authentic version of the client.

Is there a way to do this properly?

Comment: You might have better luck with this question on [security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/), but I'd recommend giving a concrete example of your code regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't rely on a "version check" in this sense.  Instead, use signed jars, which guarantees the jar cannot be modified and still run, and use the signature field in the manifest file in communications with your server to determine if the client is an authorized version.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signindex.html

Comment: What's wrong with a version check?

Comment: It's too easily spoofed.  The signature ensures that your jar is not tampered with at all, even if your "VERSION.TXT" file is the same.  Further, you can use the a cryptographic hash that's generated by the signature as a deployment artifact version (and I guarantee will be different for every build), to easily determine what clients are "allowed" regardless of the "version" which is usually a marketing construct.

Comment: You use a minecraft block as your avatar, so I'll assume you're familiar with how minecraft mods just add new classes into the jar.  With jar signing, a user couldn't modify the content of the jar and still run the application.  With a simple "version check" you could.

Comment: Ok, I understand it. I will try and understand the jar signing right now.